# Awk вывод между двумя паттернами

Tags: awk

Как вывести в терминале между двумя шаблонами?

К примеру

```
echo You need emergency help | awk /You/,/help/
   You need emergency help
```

Мне нужен вывод только: need emergency. Вся строка мне не нужна

Comment: awk '$1 == "You", $1 == "help" {print $2 FS $3}'

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$1 == "You", $1 == "help" {print $2 FS $3}'
```

Comment: Вам не кажется, что чего-то не хватает? Поправте  ответ.